# Create a constrained randomized list of elements using two rules

Tags: r, constraints

I'm trying to create a randomized list of 32 items (these are experimental items) using R, with the following constraints:

1. Items 1 to 24 have three different conditions, being item 1 condition 1; item 2 condition 2; item 3 condition 3; item 4 condition 1; item 5 condition 2; and so on. The constraint is that there cannot be more than three consecutive items of the same condition. E.g. 1,4,7,10 is not acceptable.
2. Items 25-32 all have condition 10, and there cannot be more than two consecutive items of this condition. EG 25, 26, 27 is not acceptable.

Also, I need 32 different item orders that meet this constraint.

I wrote this code, but the while loop seems never-ending, and I can't debug it.

````
# Define the number of items
num_items <- c(seq(1:32))
conditions <- c(rep(1:3, 8), rep(10, 8))
items <- data.frame(cbind(num_items, conditions))

check_constraint_it <- function(items) {
  consecutive_condition_count <- 1
  for (i in 2:nrow(items)) {
    if (items$conditions[i] <9) {
      if (items$conditions[i] == items$conditions[i - 1]) {
        consecutive_condition_count <- consecutive_condition_count + 1
        if (consecutive_condition_count > 3) {
          return(FALSE)
        }
      } else {
        consecutive_condition_count <- 1
      }
    }
    else {
      if (items$conditions[i] == items$conditions[i - 1]) {
        consecutive_condition_count <- consecutive_condition_count + 1
        if (consecutive_condition_count > 2) {
          return(FALSE)
        }
      } else {
        consecutive_condition_count <- 1
      }
    }
    }
  return(TRUE)
}


# Randomly shuffle items until the constraint is met
items_m <- data.frame()

for (i in 1:32) {
  while (TRUE) {
    # Create a copy of the items dataframe
    current_items <- items
    
    # Randomly shuffle items
    shuffled_items <- sample(current_items$num_items)
    current_items$shuffled_order <- shuffled_items
    
    # Check if the constraint is met
    if (check_constraint_it(current_items)) {
      items_m <- rbind(items_m, current_items$shuffled_order)
      break
    }
  }
}```


I tried the code shown above, and I expected that each order were saved at the "items_m" dataframe.
````

Answer (score 3):

You can define a `checker` function and then verify each randomized order. If `checker` returns `TRUE`, keep it; Otherwise, skip it.

## Code Example

```
checker <- function(v) {
  with(
    rle(v),
    all(lengths[values == 10] < 3) && all(lengths <= 3)
  )
}

n <- nrow(items)
l <- 32
res <- NULL
repeat {
  if (length(res) == l) break
  idx <- sample.int(n)
  if (checker(items$conditions[idx])) {
    res <- c(res, list(items[idx, ]))
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

I did not debug your code, but I would propose this alternate solution. `rle` provides a fast way to get the counts of consecutive items in a vector, we can use the to simplify your checker.

```
df = data.frame(
  item = 1:32,
  cond = c(rep(1:4, 6), rep(10, 8))
)

check_constraint = function(idx) {
  runs = rle(df$cond[idx])
  if(with(runs, max(lengths[values == 10])) > 2) return(FALSE)
  if(with(runs, max(lengths)) > 3) return(FALSE)
  TRUE
}

orders = list()
n_found = 0
while(length(orders) < 32) {
  candidate_order = sample(1:32, size = 32)
  if(check_constraint(candidate_order)) {
    n_found = n_found + 1
    orders[[n_found]] = candidate_order
  }
}
```

You can then use one of the saved orders like this (example for the 2nd one):

```
## access an order
df[orders[[2]], ]
#    item cond
# 2     2    2
# 32   32   10
# 17   17    1
# 7     7    3
# 29   29   10
# 20   20    4
# 9     9    1
# 8     8    4
# 1     1    1
# 5     5    1
# 27   27   10
# 4     4    4
# 22   22    2
# 19   19    3
# 25   25   10
# 13   13    1
# 3     3    3
# 28   28   10
# 21   21    1
# 23   23    3
# 14   14    2
# 26   26   10
# 31   31   10
# 10   10    2
# 30   30   10
# 11   11    3
# 12   12    4
# 24   24    4
# 6     6    2
# 15   15    3
# 18   18    2
# 16   16    4
```

Comment: This worked perfectly! Thank you so much!